# systemd-networkd .network ignored within systemd-nspawn container

Tags: systemd-networkd, systemd-nspawn

I'm fiddling with `systemd-nspawn` containers on my RaspberryPi. So far booting works fine. I use the --network-veth and --network-bridge=br0 options and bridging did work well with a kvm virtual machine.

Now I want to configure the container IP to a specific address and created a `/etc/systemd/network/host.network` file which seems to be ignored as the container gets its IP via DHCP.

This is the file.

```
[Match]
Name=host0

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=192.168.0.16/24
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

systemd-networkd is running:

```
root@bluehost-debian:~# systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Do 2016-09-01 21:10:54 UTC; 12min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 69 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
   CGroup: /machine.slice/machine-bluecloud.scope/system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─69 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Sep 01 21:10:54 bluehost-debian systemd-networkd[69]: host0           : link configured
Sep 01 21:10:54 bluehost-debian systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Sep 01 21:10:55 bluehost-debian systemd-networkd[69]: host0           : gained carrier
Sep 01 21:10:58 bluehost-debian systemd-networkd[69]: host0           : DHCPv4 address 192.168.0.143/24 via 192.168.0.1
Sep 01 21:10:58 bluehost-debian systemd-networkd[69]: host0           : link configured
```

udev tells me that my value for the Name field should be ok. Why is it ignored?

```
udevadm info /sys/class/net/host0
P: /devices/virtual/net/host0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/net/host0
E: IFINDEX=2
E: INTERFACE=host0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
```

Otherwise the network works ok. Tried `/etc/network/interfaces` but this did not work in startup but only with ifup... (allow-hotplug host0 ...)

I'm a little stuck so help is appreciated.

Comment: Ok... in the container I updated systemd to latest from jessie-backports which got me networkctl. This showed me the file currently used for network configuration. which was not mine. rename my file to `00-host.network` and that did the trick... read something about a bug with network in the container until 217... debian had 215 and in backports is 230.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to configure the container IP to a specific address and created a /etc/systemd/network/host.network file which seems to be ignored as the container gets its IP via DHCP.
>
> Ok... in the container I updated systemd to latest from jessie-backports which got me networkctl. This showed me the file currently used for network configuration. which was not mine. rename my file to 00-host.network and that did the trick...

Well done.

To be clear, the problem was that `host.network` sorts last.  You needed to provide a file with a name that sorted before the default  `80-host0.network` in `/lib/systemd/network/`, or which had the same filename (or mask it by creating a file with the same name, pointing to /dev/null).

> read something about a bug with network in the container until 217... debian had 215 and in backports is 230.

### Alternative: /etc/network/interfaces

> Tried /etc/network/interfaces but this did not work in startup but only with ifup... (allow-hotplug host0 ...)

/etc/network/interfaces worked fine for me (with DHCP).  However I worried that allow-hotplug might not work inside the container, so I had used `auto host0` instead.  This should be safe as `host0` is created very early on by nspawn.